# Java classes : how to check for compatibility to avoid classloading / compatibility issues at runtime

Tags: java

I have an Ant-based build system and I thought I might write a python script to test all compiled / jarred classes in a directory hierarchy so as to avoid problems that might arise from different version being used in compile time versus runtime.

Naively the script initially checked the **sha256** hash of all classes found in various **jar**, **war** and **ear** files and complains if the same class is found with a different hash. However this produces too many false alarms.

For instance the class **org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap** is available in both **commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar** and **commons-collections-2.1.1.jar** with different hashes. Obviously this criterion was too strict. In the end however, the only way I could produce the same hash was by doing the following:

```
javap commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar.exploded/org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.class | sort | grep -v Compiled\ from\ |  sha256sum -
javap commons-collections-2.1.1.jar.exploded/org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.class | sort | grep -v Compiled\ from\ |  sha256sum -
```

And these are indeed the same, but this, (especially the *grep -v* and the *sort*) is very unsatisfactory. Is there a better way to test that all classes in a directory hierarchy are compatible so as to avoid unexpected runtime problems?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you test the application before you deploy it into production.  If there are any libraries which you don't think are needed you should remove them or you should test them.

You shouldn't be running a library in production which you have never used before even in development.

This will minimise a wide variety of problems which could happen in production.

Comment: I understand that. However an automated way to diagnose class incompatibility issues without even requiring testing wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I would imagine it might encourage people to run code in production without testing it first.